# How to randomly assign value to a column from a subquery in SQL?

Tags: mysql

I have been struggling with something in MySQL.
Here is my problem:

I have a query returning a list of dates, here it is:

`SELECT MIN(act_date) AS d FROM acts WHERE act_type_id = 'PA' GROUP BY contact_id;`

Now, I want to randomly assign values from this list to each row of another query so that the distribution of dates stay the same. Then, my higher level query will compute things based on that dates. Here is the higher level query:

```
SELECT 
    a1.contact_id,
    DATEDIFF(d, MAX(a1.act_date)) / 365 AS recency,
    COUNT(a1.amount) AS frequency,
    AVG(a1.amount) AS avg_amount,
    MAX(a1.amount) AS max_amount,
    DATEDIFF(d, MIN(a1.act_date)) / 365 AS seniority,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN payment_method_id = 'CH' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS nb_ch,
    0 AS switched
FROM
    acts a1
WHERE
    YEAR(act_date) >= 1991 
GROUP BY 1
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN act_type_id = 'PA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

I don't really know if it is possible to do that with SQL. Should I rather import my data in R at first in order to do it?

Thank you all very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes:

A subquery that returns a scalar can be used in the SELECT list.

The MySQL `RAND()` function returns a pseudo-random value.

We can use an expression in an `ORDER BY` clause.

...

For small sets, or where performance isn't a concern, we can do something like this:

```
SELECT ...
     , 0 AS switched
     , ( SELECT MIN(r.act_date)
           FROM acts r
          WHERE r.act_type_id = 'PA'
          GROUP BY r.contact_id
          ORDER BY RAND() 
          LIMIT 1
       ) AS act_date_min_by_contact_id_rand 
  FROM acts a1
       ...
```

Comment: This query makes SQL Workbench give up. It has been running for minutes through R now, I'll tell you if it works or not, thanks!

Comment: There's a reason my answer mentions "*for small sets*" and "*where performance isn't a concern*"   The subquery is going to be evaluated for *each* row returned for the outer query. And that is going to be expensive.